# How do I return my auto-generated ID in my MyBatis object?

Tags: mysql, insert, mybatis, auto-generate

I’m using `MySQL 5.5.46` with `MyBatis 3.3` and `Spring 4.2`.  I have a table with a primary key column that is of type `VARCHAR(32)`.  In my mapping file, I have this statement.  Notice that I use MySql’s `uuid()` to auto-generate an ID.  How do I then take this ID and populate it in the returned object?  I’m trying `LAST_INSERT_ID()` but that isn’t doing it …

```
<insert id="insertMyObject" parameterType="org.mainco.myproject.domain.MyObject" keyProperty="id"  keyColumn="id">
    insert into cb_myproject_sync_entity_link(id, links_self, links_schools, links_teachers, links_students, links_sections, links_grade_levels, links_contacts)
    values(replace(uuid(), '-', ''),#{linksSelf}, #{linksSchools}, #{linksTeachers}, #{linksStudents}, #{linksSections}, #{linksGradeLevels}, #{linksContacts})     
   <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="String" order="AFTER">SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();</selectKey>
</insert>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MyBatis, how to get the auto generated key of an insert? \[MySql\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507508/mybatis-how-to-get-the-auto-generated-key-of-an-insert-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this setting in mybatis configuration:

```
<settings>
   <setting name="useGeneratedKeys" value="true"/>
</settings>
```